# Simple issue with including .js script

Tags: javascript, html

I'm sure this is the simplest bit of code you'll see all day; I feel silly asking for help on this, but I've been staring at it for an hour and am going crazy because I can't figure out WHY it won't work.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="include.js"></SCRIPT>
</head>
<body onload="test()">
<p id="center"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

include.js

```
function test()
{
  document.getElementByID('center').innerHTML="testing";
}
```

When I open index in a browser window, it just gives me a blank page. I tried putting an alert window in the first line of the test() function, and it alerted, so it's getting that far. If I put the alert after the "testing" line, it doesn't happen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Id shouldn't be capitalized.  "getElementById"

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
getElementByID
```

with

```
getElementById
```

But you should [look at the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) to find those errors. You can't go very far without such a tool.

Comment: Thank you. I knew I'd kick myself.

Comment: I hope you learn **how** to avoid those bugs in the future. Please really read the link I gave.

Answer (score 0):

should be getElementById - not ID at the end!

Try hitting f12 in your browser. You should get an error console to help with these simple issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.onload=function test()
{
  document.getElementById('center').innerHTML="testing";
}
```